# How can I access S3 folder from hadoop in AWS EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs, amazon-emr

I want to create single `InputStream` from multiple files in S3 folder using HDFS methods of something similar.
The code is running on Hadoop 3.2.1 in AWS EMR on the master node, that means I have a `Configuration` object.
I’ve tried it with the following code:

```java
try (FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
     InputStream inputStream = fileSystem.open(new Path("s3://<bucket>/<folder>")))
{
    ...
}
```

And it gave me the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3://<bucket>/<folder>, expected: hdfs://ip-172-31-70-194.ec2.internal:8020` (of course `<bucket>` and `<folder>` are just fillers)

Is there any other way I can do it?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, how is that supposed to work? You cannot write data directly into a folder / prefix itself, neither on a normal file system nor on s3.

Comment: I just want to read from the bucket without using S3Client if possible

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440643/illegalargumentexception-wrong-fs-when-specifying-input-output-from-s3-instead ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IllegalArgumentException, Wrong FS when specifying input/output from s3 instead of hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440643/illegalargumentexception-wrong-fs-when-specifying-input-output-from-s3-instead)