# I am trying to write a dataframe to a single file in s3 with a desired file name in pyspark. I am able to do this in scala but gives below error in py

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

My pyspark code tries to create a dataframe and to write the dataframe to a an s3 location. After doing this i will have one file with name as part-***, I am trying to rename this file using hadoop file util libraries but getting the below error always. Is this operation possible in pyspark?
Note: I cannot use boto3 here since i will be running this on EMR.

**The code that i am using in pyspark is below:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test_rename").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

l = [['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3'], ['Col1Value1', 'Col2Value1', 'Col3Value1'], ['Col1Value2', 'Col2Value2', 'Col3Value2']]
#Read the string data into a DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame(l[1:],l[0])

df.coalesce(1) \
    .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .save("s3://<bucket>/<prefix>")

from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
java_import(spark._jvm, 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path')

fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
file = fs.globStatus(sc._jvm.Path('s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/part*'))[0].getPath().getName()
fs.rename(sc._jvm.Path('s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/' + file), sc._jvm.Path('mydata.csv'))
fs.delete(sc._jvm.Path('s3://<bucket>/<prefix>'), True)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

````
File "/mnt/tmp/spark-471166fb-d7c7-4839-a308-2e3f5c01c185/test_rename.py", line 20, in <module>
    file = fs.globStatus(sc._jvm.Path('s3://<bucket>/<prefix>/part*'))[0].getPath().getName()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 196, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: s3://<bucket>/<prefix>, expected: hdfs://<emr-ip>:8020```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IllegalArgumentException, Wrong FS when specifying input/output from s3 instead of hdfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440643/illegalargumentexception-wrong-fs-when-specifying-input-output-from-s3-instead)

Comment: That link only refers to scala spark code. I have no issues doing this in scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop's FileSystem needs an URI to determine the client implementation. You can provide it during initialisation of the `FileSystem` object either using the `uri` constructor parameter or `fs.defaultFS` configuration parameter.

```
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jvm.java.net.URI("s3://bucket/"), spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
fs.listStatus(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("s3://bucket/prefix/"))

// Or
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.defaultFS", "s3://bucket/")
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
```

It's the same for both Python and Scala; you're accessing the same Java objects using [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/about.html) really. If the same code worked in Scala, probably you had different `fs.defaultFS` value in the Hadoop configuration.

Please see `FileSystem`'s [source code](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.java#L287) and `fs.defaultFS` [description](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.5/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml).

> The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation. The uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming the FileSystem implementation class. The uri's authority is used to determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Have been trying to get this working all day

Comment: You're welcome. Please feel free to mark this as the accepted answer.